# Permitir solo letras y números en Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

Necesito una expresión regular en Python que verifique si una cadena tiene solo letras y números y en ese caso devuelva verdadero.

Tengo este código pero no parece funcionar:

```
regex = re.compile('[^[a-zA-Z0-9]*]')

return regex.search(cadena) is None
```

Answer (score 3):

Te puede servir este

```
regex = re.compile(r'[\W_]')
```

Si no es obligatorio usar regex, también te puede servir el método integrado [isalnum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)

```
cadena.isalnum() # Devuelve True o False
```

Comment: Si no requiere expresión regular, sin duda el método `ìsalnum()` es la mejor respuesta! Muy buena voto positivo!

Answer (score 2):

El patrón `\w` reconoce letras y digitos.

Si antepones un "^", obligas a reconocer desde la primera posición. Si agregas un "$", obligas a reconocer la última posición.

```
import re
patron = re.compile("^\w+$")

tests = ["", "a", "A", "12", "A23", "A-23B", "z ", " con espacio"]
for test in tests:
    if patron.match(test):
        print(f"'{test}' es valido")
    else:
        print(f"'{test}' no es valido")
```

produce

```
'' no es valido
'a' es valido
'A' es valido
'12' es valido
'A23' es valido
'A-23B' no es valido
'z ' no es valido
' con espacio' no es valido
```

Answer (score 2):

Estrictamente hablando, la forma más sencilla de alcanzar ese objetivo es a través del método `isalnum`. La alternativa más rapida mediante expresiones regulares sería a través de `r'^\w+$'` y una alternativa que pareciera ser más especifica es `r'^[0-9A-Za-z]+$'` .

**¿Cúal es mejor?**

`r'^\w+$'`

- Hace match con caracteres de palabras compuestos por letras alfanuméricas y `_`, a partir de los caracteres **UNICODE**. Es importante recalcar que los caracteres alfanuméricos de manera estricta no estan restringidos a aquellos utilizados en el idiomas como el español, ingles, etc. Idiomas como el Chino, tiene sus representaciones propias y esta expresión considera esas variaciones entre lenguajes. [Ver documentación.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- Toma el carácter `_` como parte de la palabra. Podría ser no necesariamente lo que quieres.

`r'^[0-9A-Za-z]+$'`

- Es una expresión mas específica que esta estrictamente vinculada únicamente con los caracteres alfanuméricos, sin contar en ellos el `_` como  lo haría la primera opción.
- Se limita a los caracteres alfanuméricos del español, ingles y otros idiomas similares.

**Ejemplo.**

```py
import re

r1 = r'^\w*$'
r2 = r'^[0-9A-Za-z]+$'

aE = 'A' # A en español
aC = '阿' # A en chino

# Regex \w
print(re.match(r1, aE)) # Match
print(re.match(r1, aC)) # Match

# Regex [0-9....]
print(re.match(r2, aE)) # Match
print(re.match(r2, aC)) # None

# Metodo isalnum
print(aE.isalnum()) # True
print(aC.isalnum()) # True
```

Por último, una alternativa que podría estar disponible en otros entornos que usan expresiones regulares es a través de [clases POSIX](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) que resultaría en `^[[:alnum:]]+$` , lamentablemente la biblioteca estandar de expresiones regulares en python no cuenta con soporte para esta última.

En conclusión tu mejor alternativa es el método `isalnum` debido a que no incluye caracteres externos a los que deseas y soporta caracteres UNICODE garantizado tu proposito en distintos idiomas. Es importante tener en cuenta que estos pequeños detalles sobre caracteres unicode, clases POSIX, etc son dependientes del entorno donde se estan utilizando las expresiones regulares, otros entornos pueden llegar a tener distintas implementaciones conforme a esos aspectos.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es posible usa `re.match()` dentro de la función que crees y después retorna un booleano, así le obligas a que se cumpla desde el principio:

```
def eval_string(x:str):
    return re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', x) is not None

print(eval_string("hola"))
print(eval_string("111"))
print(eval_string("#"))
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
False
```

Usamos `re.match()` porque queremos evaluar que en la cadena se cumpla la expresión regular desde el principio. Si usas `re.search()` lo que haces es que se cumpla, en algún punto de la cadena la condición.

#### explicación de la expresión

- `a-z`: le indicamos que busque cualquier letra en el rango a-z (cualquiera del diccionario
- `A-Z`: lo mismo que arriba pero en mayusculas
- `0-9`: lo mismo pero en el rango de todos los números
- `+`: indicamos que lo busque un número indeterminado de veces, mientras se cumplan las condiciones de arriba.
- `$`: le indicamos que queremos que la cadena acabe. Es decir que se cumpla extrictamente la condición de que haya solo letras y números hasta la última posición.
- corchetes: entre corchetes se ponen todos los caracteres aceptados.